# PhpStorm / WebStorm Shortcut for editing an existing live template

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, live-templates

Is there a shortcut for editing an existing live template in PhpStorm / WebStorm? When I use ⇧+⌘+A (on Mac) and write the name of the live template I get only an option to turn on/off this live template (screenshot) but it would be cool to be navigated from here to the editing window.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't, unfortunately. But you can still use ⇧+⌘+A, type the name of LT and you should be able to go just right there from ⇧+⌘+A.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the only thing i get using ⇧+⌘+A is an option to turn the live template on or off. I've updated the question and added a screenshot of what i get using ⇧+⌘+A

Comment: What if you select the first option (on a screenshot) called "vardump live template"? This one moves me to settings page.

Comment: Facepalm! i'm so blind! I don't know why, but I didn't register this option at all. Maybe because i thought it would be only the description for the following one.

Thank you very much!!!